# Vbos draw black when trying to pass colour data from a vertex to a fragment shader

Tags: java, opengl, shader, lwjgl

When trying to pass a vec4(of colour data) form a vertex shader to a fragment shader, the resulting output of the fragment shader draws a black vbo.

I have tried changing where i bind the program, using flat and adding more glfwWindowHints. What is quite strange too is there is no compiling or linking errors from the shader and the shader program.

I have also directly tested the fragment shader and found it to work, aswhell as the binding of data and drawing of the mesh.

Rendering:

```
        GL45.glBindVertexArray(vao);

        program.bind();

        GL45.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL45.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        meshes.forEach(mesh -> mesh.draw(vao));

        GL45.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL45.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

        program.unbind();

        GL45.glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Drawing the meshes:

```
        bindData(vao);

        if(beforeDraw != null)
            beforeDraw.call();

        GL45.glDrawElements(GL45.GL_TRIANGLES, num_vertecies,  GL45.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        if(afterDraw != null)
            afterDraw.call();
```

Creating ShaderProgram:

```
/*Called by constructor where it chooses to detach and delete the previous shaders after this is called*/

        this.program = glCreateProgram();

        for(Shader s : shaders) glAttachShader(program, s.get());

        glLinkProgram(program);

        glValidateProgram(program);

        if(validateProgram(program) == GL_FALSE)
            printProgramErrorLog(program);
```

Creating Shaders:

```
       shader = glCreateShader(getShaderType());

        glShaderSource(shader, source);

        glCompileShader(shader);

        if(validateShader(shader) == GL_FALSE) {
            printShaderErrorLog(shader);
            delete();
        }
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex;
layout(location = 1) in float data;

out vec4 object_color;

void main(void){

    gl_Position = vec4(vertex, 1.0f);

    object_color = vec4(0.f, data, 1.0f, 1.0f);

}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec4 object_color;

out vec4 FragColor;

void main(void){

    FragColor = object_color;

}
```

The expected result is a output of an vbo with a colour.

Comment: How do you specify the arrays of vertex attribute data?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I call a lambda before the draw call, which executes `GL45.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL45.GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * 4,0);
 GL45.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 1, GL45.GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * 4, 2);`

Comment: If a named buffer object is bound, then the last parameter of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is treated as a byte offset into this buffer. So for the the attribute `"data"` the parameter has to be 3*4

Comment: Thank you very much, i had wondered but i didn't know if it automatically did that via the type paramiter . But of course this has not fixed the black screen issue .

Comment: Are all the components of  the vertex coordinates in range [-1.0, 1.0]?

Comment: Yes  (have to get to 15 characters in length) .

Comment: if you substitute `object_color` with `vec4(1, 0, 0, 1)`, do you see a red output?

Comment: Yes, which makes me think it could be a LWJGL / OpenGL problem. (Unless i'm missing out something really simple)